# Manage sessions in Cloud Code and current.user on Parse.com

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm going to try to explain my problem the clearest possible way.
I'm using the jssdk 1.6.7.
In order to manage the sessions I use parse-express-cookie-session:

```
var parseExpressHttpsRedirect = require('parse-express-https-redirect');
var parseExpressCookieSession = require('parse-express-cookie-session');
app.use(parseExpressHttpsRedirect());
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.cookieParser('mykey'));
app.use(parseExpressCookieSession({
  fetchUser: true,
  cookie: { maxAge: 3600000 }
}));
app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  Parse.User.logIn(req.body.username, req.body.password).then(function() {
    res.send(true);
  }, function(error) {
    res.send(error);
  });
});
```

When I do login from the website, the cookie gets created without any problem. When an user access to an url such as /prueba I retrieve the user with:

```
app.get('/prueba', function(req, res) {
  res.send(Parse.User.current());
});
```

The problem is when on Javascript I call the cloud method on the client-side, Parse.User.current() and request.user are always null and I can't get the currentUser. Any ideas?

Edit for more info:

When I do for example:

```
Parse.Cloud.run("getNumbersWords", {id: country, userc: cUser}, {
  success: function(count) {
    numberWords = count;
    changePalabra();
  },
  error: function(error) {
    console.log(error);
   }
});
```

My getNumbersWords is:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('getNumbersWords', function (request, response) {
  console.error(request);
  var query = new Parse.Query("Pais");
  query.get(request.params.id).then( function(pais) {
    var queryP = new Parse.Query('Palabras');
    queryP.equalTo('idioma', pais.get('idioma').toLowerCase());
    return queryP.count();
  }).then( function(count) {
    response.success(count);
  }, function(error) {
    response.error({'resp': error.code, 'message': error.message});
  });
});
```

Parse.User.current(), request.user and request.params.sessionToken are null.

Comment: get the user making the request with `req.user`

Comment: thanks for your help, I edited my post for adding more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so after a lot of digging I have worked it out. 
First you need to do something like this in your client-side:

```
Parse.User.logIn(usern, pass, {
  success: function(user) {
    var sess = user.get("sessionToken");
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: "json",
      data: {sessionToken: sess},
      url: "/login",
      success: function(resp) {
        console.log(resp)
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  },
  error: function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

In your server-side, your /login post must be this:

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  var sessionToken = req.body.sessionToken;

  Parse.User.become(sessionToken).then(function (user) {
    res.send(true);
  }, function (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.send(false);
  });
});
```

Et voilà. The "become" method puts a cookie in the browser.